# How to get Dash to open folders?

Tags: nautilus, unity-dash

<strike>When I search for a folder in my home directory using the Dash, the folder shows up. However, when I click on the folder, nothing happens.</strike>

How can I get nautilus to launch when I click on the folder?

I had a double nautilus.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications/ which is what was breaking things! Once I deleted it, the problem went away. Therefore, this question is not a good question.

Please vote to close it.

Comment: From what I understand, you are searching for a folder, you click the folder, the Dash fades away, and then nothing happens?

Comment: Yes, I suspect that it might be that since I have multiple file managers and desktop environments Unity doesn't know which is the default? It works for files, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is reset the association to open folders with Nautilus.

1. Open Nautilus, browse to any folder, and right click.
2. Choose *Open with Other Application*
3. Choose *Files*. *Files* is the display name of `/usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`

Comment: This caused me to look around for extra desktop files, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what you mentioned above, I believe the fact of having multiple file managers is causing some kind of problem. Try reconfiguring nautilus with this command:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus

If that doesn't work, reinstalling Unity should do the trick:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get install unity

Comment: It actually didn't work. Go figure!